# LM_36320 Session task instance [s_m_scdone]: Execution failed

Tags: session, informatica, informatica-powercenter, scd

Please help me out im getting this error in informatica powercenter in workflow monitor.

After starting workflow i'm getting this error

LM_36320 Session task instance [s_m_scdone]: Execution failed.

How to solve this error??

Comment: Hi - the information you’ve supplied is not enough for anyone to help you. Please update your question with all the relevant information from the log file and explain what you’re process is doing, what step it is failing at, etc

Comment: Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code Message
ERROR 13-06-2023 16:03:41 node01 10604 LM_36320 Session task instance [s_m_updstr]: Execution failed. This is the error message i'm receiving after running workflow for update strategy.

Comment: This still doesn't tell me anything useful. What does it say in the log file that shows what was running when the error happened, what the actual error was, etc? You may need to turn up the logging level in order to generate enough information

Comment: This is the Workflow log. Please check / provide info from s_m_scdone session log.